# How to load 3D models into Java?

Tags: 3d, java, 3d-meshes, blender, lwjgl

Using LWJGL what is the easiest way to load a 3D model to be drawn on screen?

I know LWJGL doesn't have built in loading support so I am looking for a small library that would help to load specifically .blend files.

Answer (score 9):

The best way in my opinion is to write your own parser for .obj exported with Blender or your preferred 3D modeling software. It will really only take you a maximum of one hour and you won't have to worry about distribution/licence issues. Here is a video about this question: http://youtu.be/izKAvSV3qk0.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to build you own loader that can for example load [.OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files or maybe your own format thats custom made for your game. 
Blender files however I'm not sure.

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of "easiest way"? :-)

Comment: +1 I find it funny how to the highest rated answer (by Oskar) says essentially the same thing, but you get downvoted. :)

Comment: Ease may be subjective here, but it certainly is the smartest way to do it. .obj files have a simple structure, and writing a loader/parser for the format is simple compared to other formats. It may be considered to be easier as a long-term gain when you consider that you will be in direct control of the source that loads your models, in case something strange happens; not at the mercy of a black box or some unfamiliar code.

Answer (score 3):

You may find [JAGaToo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jagatoo/) to be useful. It has loaders for MD2/3/5, OBJ, and some other model formats.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) - it has model loading capabilities for many different model files and is based on LWJGL so you may be able to adapt it to your needs.